# Regular expression for YYYY-WW based dates

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I have the following [valid] regex expression that I am trying to put into a VBA app:

```
(?<year>(\d{2}){0,2}[-\/]?)(?<week>(\d{2}))
```

I keep getting error 5017. Method 'Execute' is not supported on object 'IRegExp2'.

But if I ditch the named captures and plug in:

```
((\d{2}){0,2}[-\/]?)((\d{2}))
```

Am I right in assuming that the "vbscript" sour-tasting flavour of regex doesn't support named groups?

Is there another standard (to Windows) library I can reference in VBA to get a better regex parser?

I'd love to use the C# one as that worked immediately and pulled my groups out but I'm constrained to VBA as my whole app plugin is in MS Office.

Comment: I do not think that named groups are [supported](http://www.regular-expressions.info/vbscript.html).

Comment: They are not, for sure. I guess that in order to use .NET regex, you could write some sort of a command-line tool that you would call from VBA and get the result after it finishes. Just an idea. Or create a COM add-in for custom processing your documents.

Comment: You should still be able to use normal capturing groups. You can refer to them by number: `\1` for the first group, `\2` for the second, etc.

Answer (score 0):

VBA-compatible regex for `YYYY-WW` (between 1900-01 and 2999-52) is:

```
([1-2][0-9])([0-9][0-9])[-\/](0[1-9]|[1-4][0-9]|5[0-2])
```

Which will exclude weeks 53 through 99.

To get the century, year, week use the `SubMatches` collection to get the different capturing groups.

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestYYYYWWRegex()

    Dim objRegex As New RegExp
    Dim objMatches As MatchCollection
    Dim varTests As Variant
    Dim varTest As Variant
    Dim strMessage As String

    objRegex.Pattern = "([1-2][0-9])([0-9][0-9])[-\/](0[1-9]|[1-4][0-9]|5[0-2])"
    varTests = Array("2017-13", "1975-09", "2016-63", "zz78-0g", "1978-00", "1234-56", "1234-01", "YYYY-WW")

    For Each varTest In varTests
        Set objMatches = objRegex.Execute(CStr(varTest))
        If objMatches.Count > 0 Then
            With objMatches
                strMessage = "Matched: " & CStr(varTest)
                strMessage = strMessage & " C: " & .Item(0).SubMatches(0)
                strMessage = strMessage & " Y: " & .Item(0).SubMatches(1)
                strMessage = strMessage & " W: " & .Item(0).SubMatches(2)
            End With
        Else
            strMessage = "No match for: " & CStr(varTest)
        End If

        'check test case
        Debug.Print strMessage

    Next varTest

End Sub
```

Test cases:

```
Matched: 2017-13 C: 20 Y: 17 W: 13
Matched: 1975-09 C: 19 Y: 75 W: 09
No match for: 2016-63
No match for: zz78-0g
No match for: 1978-00
No match for: 1234-56
Matched: 1234-01 C: 12 Y: 34 W: 01
No match for: YYYY-WW
```